# Why does my ble app crash when I move a function call to a different button?

Tags: android, crash, bluetooth-lowenergy, psoc

I am currently attempting to make the app I am developing more simple to use but I am running into an issue trying to consolidate the amount of buttons needed to establish connection to a PSoC 4 BLE. In the end I want one button to handle searching, connecting, and discovery of services. But when I copy and past the code (for search, connecting, and discovering) under the method that handles activating the Bluetooth radio, the app crash when it encounters the scan callback. I am still new to Android app development and I am trying to use the debugger but I seem to be stuck. The first snippet of code is what I am trying to do, the second snippet is the scan function that is being called. The following snippet is the debugger output.

```java
//what I am trying to do
    public void startBluetooth(View view) {

        /** Find BLE service and adapter */
        final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =
                (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();

        /** Ensures Bluetooth is enabled on the device.  If Bluetooth is not currently enabled,
        // fire an intent to display a dialog asking the user to grant permission to enable it. */
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BLE);
        }

        /** Start the BLE Service */
        Log.d(TAG, "Starting BLE Service");
        Intent gattServiceIntent = new Intent(this, PSoCCapSenseLEDService.class);
        bindService(gattServiceIntent, mServiceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);


        /** Disable the start button and turn on the search  button */
        start_button.setEnabled(false);
        search_button.setEnabled(true);
        Log.d(TAG, "Bluetooth is Enabled");



        // search function does not crash app
        // cannot force step into if statement, is mServiceConnected true?
        // no mServiceConnected appears to false
        // okay let's force this if statement to be executed
        // but first setting code back to normal and seeing how mServiceConnected is set

       mPSoCCapSenseLedService.scan(); // causes crash
        mPSoCCapSenseLedService.connect(); // crash
        mPSoCCapSenseLedService.discoverServices();
    }
```

```java
    public void scan() {
        /** Scan for devices and look for the one with the service that we want
         *   UUID ending in F0 i.e. the ledcapsense service*/
        UUID capsenseLedService = UUID.fromString(capsenseLedServiceUUID);
        UUID[] capsenseLedServiceArray = {capsenseLedService};

        /** Use old scan method for versions for different platform versions */
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            /** noinspection deprecation */
            mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(capsenseLedServiceArray, mLeScanCallback);
        } else { /** New BLE scanning introduced in LOLLIPOP */
            ScanSettings settings;
            List<ScanFilter> filters;
            mLEScanner = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
            settings = new ScanSettings.Builder()
                    .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)
                    .build();
            filters = new ArrayList<>();
            /** We will scan just for the CAR's UUID */
            ParcelUuid PUuid = new ParcelUuid(capsenseLedService);
            ScanFilter filter = new ScanFilter.Builder().setServiceUuid(PUuid).build();
            filters.add(filter);
            mLEScanner.startScan(filters, settings, mScanCallback);
        }
    }
```

```
this.mResolvedMethod = No such instance field: 'mResolvedMethod'
this = {MainActivity@9661} 
view = {AppCompatButton@9664} "android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton{60e52c VF.D..C.. ...P..ID 64,64-1376,256 #7f07008a app:id/start_button}"
bluetoothManager = {BluetoothManager@9665} 
 mAdapter = {BluetoothAdapter@9666} 
 shadow$_klass_ = {Class@3343} "class android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager"
 shadow$_monitor_ = 0
mBluetoothAdapter = {BluetoothAdapter@9666} 
 mBleExtSupportArr = {boolean[1]@9772} 
 mBleSupportArr = {boolean[6]@9773} 
 mBluetoothDisableBleCallback = {BluetoothAdapter$4@9774} 
 mBluetoothStateChangeCallback = {BluetoothAdapter$3@9775} 
 mContext = {Application@9688} 
 mIsBleExtSupportArrSet = false
 mIsBleSupportArrSet = false
 mLeScanClients = {HashMap@9776}  size = 0
 mLock = {Object@9777} 
 mManagerCallback = {BluetoothAdapter$2@9778} 
 mManagerService = {IBluetoothManager$Stub$Proxy@9779} 
 mMyPid = 32668
 mMyUid = 10025
 mPackageName = "iantempleton0.gmail.com.fromscratch"
 mProxyServiceStateCallbacks = {ArrayList@9781}  size = 0
 mService = {IBluetooth$Stub$Proxy@9782} 
 mServiceLock = {ReentrantReadWriteLock@9783} "java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock@366f373[Write locks = 0, Read locks = 0]"
 mStateChangedCallbacks = {ArrayList@9784}  size = 0
 mSwitchingUser = false
 mToken = {Binder@9785} 
 packageNameforEnable = ""
 shadow$_klass_ = {Class@5364} "class android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter"
 shadow$_monitor_ = 0
gattServiceIntent = {Intent@9667} "Intent { cmp=iantempleton0.gmail.com.fromscratch/.PSoCCapSenseLEDService }"
 mAction = null
 mCategories = null
 mClipData = null
 mComponent = {ComponentName@9789} "ComponentInfo{iantempleton0.gmail.com.fromscratch/iantempleton0.gmail.com.fromscratch.PSoCCapSenseLEDService}"
 mContentUserHint = -2
 mData = null
 mExtras = null
 mFlags = 0
 mForceLaunchOverTargetTask = false
 mIdentifier = null
 mLaunchOverTargetTaskId = 0
 mLaunchToken = null
 mPackage = null
 mPairActivityUserId = 0
 mPairWindowingMode = 0
 mSelector = null
 mSourceBounds = null
 mType = null
 shadow$_klass_ = {Class@3753} "class android.content.Intent"
 shadow$_monitor_ = 0
search_button = {AppCompatButton@9668} "android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton{b1d2bf5 VFED..C.. ......ID 64,256-1376,448 #7f070072 app:id/search_button}"
 mBackgroundTintHelper = {AppCompatBackgroundHelper@9792} 
 mTextHelper = {AppCompatTextHelper@9793} 
 mIsThemeDeviceDefault = false
 HOVER_INTERVAL = 300
 SEC_CLIPBOARD_DISABLED = 0
 SEC_CLIPBOARD_ENABLED = 1
 SEC_CLIPBOARD_UNKNOWN = -1
 TOUCH_DELTA = 12.0
 mActionModeFlags = 241664
 mAllowTransformationLengthChange = false
 mAttachedWindow = false
 mAutoLinkMask = 0
 mAutoSizeMaxTextSizeInPx = -1.0
 mAutoSizeMinTextSizeInPx = -1.0
 mAutoSizeStepGranularityInPx = -1.0
 mAutoSizeTextSizesInPx = {int[0]@9725} 
 mAutoSizeTextType = 0
 mBoring = {BoringLayout$Metrics@9794} "FontMetricsInt: top=-60 ascent=-52 descent=14 bottom=16 leading=0 width=441"
 mBreakStrategy = 0
 mBufferType = {TextView$BufferType@9727} "NORMAL"
 mButtonShapeAlpha = 0
 mButtonShapeColor = -570425344
 mButtonShapeLuminance = 0.0
 mButtonShapeOutlineRadius = 0
 mButtonShapeOutlineStrokeBottom = 0
 mButtonShapeOutlineStrokeDisabled = 0
 mButtonShapeOutlineStrokeEnabled = 0
 mButtonShapeOutlineStrokeHorizontal = 0
 mButtonShapeOutlineStrokeTop = 0
 mButtonShapePaint = null
 mButtonShapeRect = null
 mButtonShapeSettingEnabled = false
 mButtonShapeTextColor = null
 mButtonShapeTextColorDark = 0
 mButtonShapeTextColorLight = 0
 mCanPaste = false
 mCanTextMultiSelection = false
 mChangeWatcher = null
 mChangedSelectionBySIP = false
 mCharWrapper = null
 mClipboardChangeListener = null
 mClipboardDataFormat = 1
 mCoverManager = null
 mCurHintTextColor = 1627389952
 mCurTextColor = -570425344
 mCurrentSpellCheckerLocaleCache = null
 mCursorDrawable = null
 mCursorDrawableRes = 17304300
 mDPIMaxLength = -1
 mDPITextBuffer = null
 mDeferScroll = -1
 mDesiredHeightAtMeasure = 192
 mDeviceProvisionedState = 0
 mDisplayText = null
 mDrawStrikeAnimationValue = 0.0
 mDrawTextStrikeAnimator = null
 mDrawables = null
 mEditableFactory = {Editable$Factory@9728} 
 mEditor = null
 mEllipsisKeywordCount = -1
 mEllipsisKeywordStart = -1
 mEllipsize = null
 mEnableLinkPreview = false
 mEnableMultiSelection = true
 mFakeBold = {Boolean@9729} false
 mFilters = {InputFilter[0]@9730} 
 mFlagForGlobalLayout = false
 mFreezesText = false
 mGlobalLayoutListener = null
 mGravity = 17
 mHasPresetAutoSizeValues = false
 mHighlightColor = 1728004225
 mHighlightPaint = {Paint@9795} 
 mHighlightPath = null
 mHighlightPathBogus = true
 mHint = null
 mHintBoring = null
 mHintLayout = null
 mHintTextColor = {ColorStateList@9732} "ColorStateList{mThemeAttrs=nullmChangingConfigurations=0mStateSpecs=[[16842910, 16842919], []]mColors=[-1979711488, 1627389952]mDefaultColor=1627389952}"
 mHorizontallyScrolling = false
 mHoverEnterTime = -1
 mHoverExitTime = -1
 mHoveredSpan = null
 mHyphenationFrequency = 0
 mIncludePad = true
 mIsButtonShapeTarget = false
 mIsDebugTextClock = false
 mIsSecClipboardEnabled = -1
 mIsShowingLinkPreview = false
 TextView.mIsThemeDeviceDefault = false
 mIsThemeDeviceDefaultDark = false
 mIsTouchDown = false
 mJustificationMode = 0
 mKeycodeDpadCenterStatus = false
 mLastLayoutDirection = 0
 mLastScroll = 0
 mLastValueSentToAutofillManager = null
 mLayout = {BoringLayout@9796} 
 mLineIsDrawed = false
 mLinkTextColor = {ColorStateList@9734} "ColorStateList{mThemeAttrs=nullmChangingConfigurations=0mStateSpecs=[[]]mColors=[-49023]mDefaultColor=-49023}"
 mLinksClickable = true
 mListenerChanged = false
 mListeners = null
 mLocalesChanged = false
 mMarquee = null
 mMarqueeFadeMode = 0
 mMarqueeRepeatLimit = 3
 mMaxMode = 1
 mMaxWidth = 2147483647
 mMaxWidthMode = 2
 mMaximum = 2147483647
 mMinMode = 2
 mMinWidth = 352
 mMinWidthMode = 2
 mMinimum = 192
 mMovement = null
 mMultiHighlightColor = -1728022343
 mMultiHighlightPaint = null
 mMultiSelectPopupWindow = {MultiSelectPopupWindow@9735} 
 mNeedsAutoSizeText = false
 mOldMaxMode = 1
 mOldMaximum = 2147483647
 mPasteEventListener = null
 mPenSelectionController = null
 mPreDrawListenerDetached = false
 mPreDrawRegistered = false
 mPrecomputed = null
 mPreventDefaultMovement = false
 mRestartMarquee = false
 mRestrictionPolicy = null
 mSavedHintLayout = null
 mSavedLayout = {BoringLayout@9796} 
 mSavedMarqueeModeLayout = null
 mScroller = null
 mSemClipboardManager = null
 mShadowColor = 0
 mShadowDx = 0.0
 mShadowDy = 0.0
 mShadowRadius = 0.0
 mSingleLine = false
 mSkipUpdateDisplayText = false
 mSoftInputEnabled = true
 mSpacingAdd = 0.0
 mSpacingMult = 1.0
 mSpannable = null
 mSpannableFactory = {Spannable$Factory@9736} 
 mStrikeThroughPaint = null
 mStylusEventListener = null
 mTempRect = null
 mTempTextPaint = null
 mText = "Search for Device"
 mTextClassificationContext = null
 mTextClassificationSession = null
 mTextClassifier = null
 mTextColor = {ColorStateList@9738} "ColorStateList{mThemeAttrs=nullmChangingConfigurations=0mStateSpecs=[[-16842910], []]mColors=[1107296256, -570425344]mDefaultColor=-570425344}"
 mTextDir = {TextDirectionHeuristics$TextDirectionHeuristicInternal@9739} 
 mTextEditSuggestionContainerLayout = 17367391
 mTextEditSuggestionHighlightStyle = 16974826
 mTextEditSuggestionItemLayout = 17367393
 mTextEffect = {SFText@9798} 
 mTextEffectFontFamily = "sans-serif-medium"
 mTextEffectLines = 0
 mTextId = 2131427338
 mTextOperationUser = null
 mTextPaint = {TextPaint@9799} 
 mTextSelectHandle = null
 mTextSelectHandleLeft = null
 mTextSelectHandleLeftRes = 17304305
 mTextSelectHandleRes = 17304307
 mTextSelectHandleRight = null
 mTextSelectHandleRightRes = 17304309
 mTextSetFromXmlOrResourceId = true
 mTextStrikeThroughEnabled = false
 mToolType = 0
 mTransformation = null
 mTransformed = "Search for Device"
 mUseDisplayText = false
 mUseFallbackLineSpacing = true
 mUseInternationalizedInput = true
 mUserSetTextScaleX = false
 mWordIteratorForMultiSelection = null
 mhasMultiSelection = false
 isPenSideButton = false
 mAccessibilityCursorPosition = -1
 mAccessibilityDelegate = null
 mAccessibilityPaneTitle = null
 mAccessibilityTraversalAfterId = -1
 mAccessibilityTraversalBeforeId = -1
 mAccessibilityViewId = 7
 mAnimator = null
 mAppRespTracker = null
 mAttachInfo = {View$AttachInfo@9743} 
 mAttributeResolutionStacks = null
 mAttributeSourceResId = null
 mAttributes = null
 mAutofillHints = null
 mAutofillId = null
 mAutofillViewId = -1
 mBackground = {RippleDrawable@9800} 
 mBackgroundRenderNode = {RenderNode@9801} 
 mBackgroundResource = 0
 mBackgroundSizeChanged = false
 mBackgroundTint = null
 mBixbyTouchFoundText = null
 mBottom = 448
 mBottomLeftRound = null
 mBottomLeftRoundColor = 0
 mBottomRightRound = null
 mBottomRightRoundColor = 0
 mCachedContentCaptureSession = null
 mCachingFailed = false
 mClipBounds = null
 mContentCaptureSession = null
 mContentDescription = null
 mContext = {MainActivity@9661} 
 mCurrentAnimation = null
 mDefaultFocusHighlight = null
 mDefaultFocusHighlightCache = null
 mDefaultFocusHighlightEnabled = true
 mDefaultFocusHighlightSizeChanged = true
 mDefaultRoundedCornerColor = 0
 mDeviceRadius = 0
 mDirectPenInput = null
 mDisablePenGestureforfactorytest = true
 mDrawableState = {int[4]@9802} 
 mDrawingCache = null
 mDrawingCacheBackgroundColor = 0
 mExplicitStyle = 0
 mExtraPaddingBottomForPreference = 0
 mFloatingTreeObserver = null
 mForegroundInfo = null
 mFrameMetricsObservers = null
 mGhostView = null
 mHasPerformedLongPress = false
 mHorizontalScrollbarPosition = 0
 mHoverPopup = null
 mHoverPopupToolTypeByApp = 0
 mHoverPopupType = 0
 mHoveringTouchDelegate = false
 mID = 2131165298
 mIgnoreNextUpEvent = false
 mImageFilterBridge = null
 mInContextButtonPress = false
 mInputEventConsistencyVerifier = null
 mIsAllowedPokeDrawLock = false
 mIsDirectPenInputEnabled = false
 mIsSetFingerHoveredInAppWidget = true
 mKeyedTags = null
 mLabelForId = -1
 mLastIsOpaque = false
 mLayerPaint = null
 mLayerType = 0
 mLayoutInsets = null
 mLayoutParams = {LinearLayout$LayoutParams@9803} 
 mLeft = 64
 mLeftPaddingDefined = false
 mListenerInfo = {View$ListenerInfo@9804} 
 mLongClickX = NaN
 mLongClickY = NaN
 mMatchIdPredicate = null
 mMatchLabelForPredicate = null
 mMeasureCache = {LongSparseLongArray@9805} "{4611691655571966032=5634997092544}"
 mMeasuredHeight = 192
 mMeasuredWidth = 1312
 mMinHeight = 192
 View.mMinWidth = 352
 mNeededToChangedScrollBarPosition = false
 mNestedScrollingParent = null
 mNextClusterForwardId = -1
 mNextFocusDownId = -1
 mNextFocusForwardId = -1
 mNextFocusLeftId = -1
 mNextFocusRightId = -1
 mNextFocusUpId = -1
 mOldHeightMeasureSpec = -2147481520
 mOldWidthMeasureSpec = 1073743136
 mOutlineProvider = {ViewOutlineProvider$1@9750} 
 mOverScrollMode = 1
 mOverlay = null
 mPaddingBottom = 40
 mPaddingLeft = 48
 mPaddingRight = 48
 mPaddingTop = 40
 mParent = {LinearLayout@9751} "android.widget.LinearLayout{dab43e2 V.E...... .......D 0,0-1440,2448}"
 mPendingCheckForLongPress = null
 mPendingCheckForTap = null
 mPerformClick = null
 mPointerIcon = null
 mPointerIconForMouse = null
 mPointerIconForStylus = null
 mPrivateFlags = -2128607216
 mPrivateFlags2 = 1611867688
 mPrivateFlags3 = 537395220
 mRecreateDisplayList = false
 mRenderNode = {RenderNode@9806} 
 mRenderNodeImageFilter = null
 mRenderNodeImageFilterClipRects = {ArrayList@9807}  size = 0
 mResources = {Resources@9707} 
 mRight = 1376
 mRightPaddingDefined = false
 mRoundRadius = -1
 mRoundScrollbarRenderer = null
 mRoundedCornerBounds = {Rect@9808} "Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0)"
 mRoundedCornerMode = 0
 mRoundedCornerRadius = 0
 mRunQueue = null
 mScrollBarPositionPadding = 0
 mScrollCache = null
 mScrollIndicatorDrawable = null
 mScrollX = 0
 mScrollY = 0
 mScrollbarVerticalPadding = 0
 mSemHorizontalScrollbarRect = {Rect@9809} "Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0)"
 mSemOffsetRequesterBounds = null
 mSemOffsetRequesterExpirer = null
 mSemOffsetRequesterTrimer = null
 mSemOnAddRemoveListener = null
 mSemSFState = 0
 mSemScrollingByScrollbar = false
 mSemScrollingVertical = true
 mSemVerticalChildOffset = 0
 mSemVerticalScrollbarRect = {Rect@9810} "Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0)"
 mSemViewFlags = 0
 mSendViewScrolledAccessibilityEvent = null
 mSendingHoverAccessibilityEvents = false
 mSmartClipDataExtractionListener = null
 mSmartClipDataTag = null
 mSourceLayoutId = 2131296284
 mStartActivityRequestWho = null
 mStateListAnimator = {StateListAnimator@9811} 
 mSystemUiVisibility = 0
 mTag = null
 mTempNestedScrollConsumed = null
 mTooltipInfo = null
 mTop = 256
 mTopLeftRound = null
 mTopLeftRoundColor = 0
 mTopRightRound = null
 mTopRightRoundColor = 0
 mTouchDelegate = null
 mTouchSlop = 32
 mTransformationInfo = null
 mTransientStateCount = 0
 mTransitionName = null
 mUnscaledDrawingCache = null
 mUnsetPressedState = null
 mUserPaddingBottom = 40
 mUserPaddingEnd = -2147483648
 mUserPaddingLeft = 48
 mUserPaddingLeftInitial = 48
 mUserPaddingRight = 48
 mUserPaddingRightInitial = 48
 mUserPaddingStart = -2147483648
 mVerticalScrollFactor = 0.0
 mVerticalScrollbarPosition = 0
 mViewFlags = 402669569
 mVisibilityChangeForAutofillHandler = null
 mWindowAttachCount = 1
 shadow$_klass_ = {Class@9494} "class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton"
 shadow$_monitor_ = -1961022475
mPSoCCapSenseLedService = null
```

Comment: please don't link to images of code, rather include them in your question please :)

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need to scan and stop the scanning before binding the service.
my ble scanning and binding is as below:

```
final BluetoothLeScanner scanner = bluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
ScanSettings settings = new ScanSettings.Builder()
    .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)
    .build();
List<ScanFilter> filters = new ArrayList<>();
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        scanner.stopScan(scanCallback);
        bindService(new Intent(ControlActivity.this, BLEService.class), 
            mServiceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

            }
        }
    }, 3500);

    scanner.startScan(filters, settings, scanCallback);
```

and for the connection callback:

```
private final ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        bleService = ((BLEService.LocalBinder) service).getService();
        try {
            bleService.connect(device mac);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            updateText("Connection Disconnected...");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        bleService = null;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

After discussing it with my professor we discovered the scan, connect, and discoverSevices callbacks were being executed near simultaneously and not sequentially. To avoid the simultaneous execution I delayed the callbacks and after extensive trial and error, these were the optimal delays I have found.

```java
    public void startBluetooth(View view) {

        /** Find BLE service and adapter */
        final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =
                (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();

        /** Ensures Bluetooth is enabled on the device.  If Bluetooth is not currently enabled,
        // fire an intent to display a dialog asking the user to grant permission to enable it. */
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BLE);
        }

        /** Start the BLE Service */
        Log.d(TAG, "Starting BLE Service");
        Intent gattServiceIntent = new Intent(this, PSoCCapSenseLEDService.class);
        bindService(gattServiceIntent, mServiceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);


        /** Disable the start button and turn on the search  button */
        start_button.setEnabled(false);
        search_button.setEnabled(true);
        Log.d(TAG, "Bluetooth is Enabled");

        new CountDownTimer(15, 1000) {
            public void onFinish() {
                // When timer is finished
                // Execute your code here
                mPSoCCapSenseLedService.scan();
            }

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                // millisUntilFinished    The amount of time until finished.
            }
        }.start();

// roughly 65ms after scanning
        new CountDownTimer(80, 1000) {
            public void onFinish() {
                // When timer is finished
                // Execute your code here
                mPSoCCapSenseLedService.connect();
            }

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                // millisUntilFinished    The amount of time until finished.
            }
        }.start();

// needs to be roughly 260ms after connection
        new CountDownTimer(340, 1000) {
            public void onFinish() {
                // When timer is finished
                // Execute your code here
                mPSoCCapSenseLedService.discoverServices();
            }

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                // millisUntilFinished    The amount of time until finished.
            }
        }.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say this but what you are doing in your answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/60694898/556495 is fundamentally wrong. Don't use arbitrary timers like this. It will definitely fail in many cases since the radio timings can differ a lot depending on the environment.

The BLE API in Android is callback based. That means the scan results are delivered as [ScanCallbacks](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanCallback). When the callback is called and the device is one you want to connect to, THAT'S when you connect.

And when you connect you supply a [BluetoothGattCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCallback) and implement the [onConnectionStateChange](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCallback#onConnectionStateChange(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt,%20int,%20int)) method. If the `state` indicates the device is now connected, THAT'S when you call `discoverServices`. The service discovery is not completed earlier than when the [onServicesDiscovered](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCallback#onServicesDiscovered(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt,%20int)) callback arrives, so first at this point you can start the GATT transactions.

And remember that you can only have one outstanding GATT operation at a time (you need to wait for the corresponding callback before you can execute another one).